# Clarify edit review screen

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

The pending edit screen is very confusing to me as someone who has never seen it before:

- It says I have 0 edits rejected.
- The rejection notice on the second line uses "this" vaguely. This question? This edit?
- It also doesn't point out that more reviews are necessary, or how many.

Original: [taken from this edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/82738)

[image]

Here is a quick proposal of what the screen could look like:

[image]

Comment: Also, a link to the question from this page would be nice.

Comment: The edit was rejected by that user, but it takes 3 users to approve/reject an edit unless the OP comes by and approves or rejects it themself.

Comment: I think this could probably be a lot more clear.  Should this suggestion be here or meta.so?

Comment: I mean, it says "Your suggested edit is pending review." and shows you who has reviewed your edit and their decision, how much *more* clear do you want?

Comment: Well... as soon as someone tells me where the proper place is to do it, I'll mock up some suggestions.

Comment: By default it doesn't show the problem you highlight with the first bullet point. Also how does yours fix this? Your edit hasn't been rejected yet. I don't think your change fixes the second bullet point, as it still implies the suggested edit, without strictly saying it.

Comment: For starters, it provides context by bookending it with the number of required and completed reviews and the number of remaining reviews necessary.  I'm sure SE's UX guys can make improvements, this is just a recommended starting point.  I don't think any UX designer would argue that the current design isn't great.

Comment: And since you're the other one that rejected it, can you explain how modifying the code formatting "deviates from the original intent of the post"?  Is that a code-review specific thing I guess?

Comment: Could you explain how yours improves on each bullet point in the question, in the question? I rejected it as [it's against site policy to change the code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/763), and you edited more than just tabs and spaces.

Comment: If I changed anything besides tabs/spaces it was an accident, but either way, here is a diff, ignoring spaces: https://i.imgur.com/DSVxMwG.png

Comment: My proposal doesn't fix everything wrong with it. That's why I said "Here is a **quick proposal** of what the screen **could** look like."

Answer (score 7):

At the time of your meta posting, one reviewer had voted to reject your suggested edit, but one vote is not sufficient to finalize the rejection.

Your suggested wording for the status is an improvement.  I think that this would be more accurate:

> 1 reviewer has voted on your suggested edit, but up to 3 votes are needed to accept or reject it.

I say "up to 3" because…

- If the first two reviewers agree, then that already constitutes a 2-out-of-3 majority.
- If the original author of the post accepts your suggested edit, then that approval is sufficient.
- A moderator can unilaterally decide to accept or reject your edit.

---

By the way, your suggested edit was rejected because it was deemed to [violate the site rules](/q/762/9357).  Indentation is a valid subject matter to be addressed in an answer, so you shouldn't change it (unless the author obviously had difficulty conveying the code the way it was originally written).

Comment: Thanks for the useful and well formatted answer!  And the indentation thing makes sense, I spend most my time on SO so code formatting being an actual part of the subject matter is new to me.  Thanks again for being courteous and helpful! :)